# Having trouble accessing firebase data with ionic creator

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm a novice IOS developer practicing building my first app. However, I am unable to access data in firebase.

For example, I have the following data:
[image: For example, I have the following data:]

I'll log into the app with the username and password which work fine and then use:

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(user.email + " " + user.username);
```

The above prints out "quanie.turner@gmail.com undefined" however the username variable is clearly defined in the database. Maybe I'm overlooking something or did something wrong. I'd appreciate any help.

Edit: I stored the data in my signup code. Here's how (btw: the scope.data array includes the username variable) :

```js
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseArray, $state) {

    var auth = $firebaseAuth();
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    var users = $firebaseArray(ref);
    
    $scope.data = {};
    
    $scope.signup = function(){
        auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.data.email, $scope.data.password).then($scope.signupSuccess);
        
      
    }
    
    $scope.signupSuccess = function(){
        users.$add($scope.data);
        $state.go('login');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two products:

1. Firebase Authentication, which allows you users to sign in to your app, and which has a user profile with a fixed set of properties.
2. Firebase Database, which allows you to store data, and which is typically used to store additional properties for a user that don't fit into their Firebase Authentication profile.

The code you have reads the user's profile from Firebase Authentication. It does not read anything from the Firebase Database. A user profile in Firebase Authentication doesn't have a `username` property. It *does* have a `displayName` property, but that again has nothing to do with the Firebase Database.

It looks like you stored the additional user information into the Firebase Database with a call like:

```
firebase.database().ref("users").push({ email: user.email, password: password, username: username })
```

While this is a valid way to store data in the database, it makes it hard to look up data for a Firebase Authentication user. The latter users are identified by their UID (`user.uid`), which is why it's custom to store additional user properties under `/users/$uid`:

```
firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).set({ email: user.email, password: password, username: username })
```

If you have that structure, you can load the additional properties for the current user with:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
usersRef.child(user.uid).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

With your current structure you *can* also look up the user. But since there may be multiple users with the same email address in your structure, you need a query for it and need to handle the fact that the query may match multiple nodes:

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
var query = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.email);
query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    console.log(userSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```

**Update**

As far as I can see you should replace your

```
users.$add($scope.data);
```

With

```
ref.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set($scope.data);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that clarification. Makes a lot of sense. Do you know then if there is a database command where I can get the current user's information from what is stored in the database (like the data stored under the username variable from the picture).

Comment: I'm adding information to my answer. But it'd be a lot easier to help if you showed how you stored this information in the database. I've taken a guess at that now.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include how I stored the data. About to read over your edits now.